# Как создать массив в векторе в C?

Tags: c

Есть вектор V с компонентами p и массив A с элементами {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, как вместить элементы из массива А в вектор V
Тут я пытался создать что-то через поинтеры но увы не получилось.
Буду благодарен любой подсказки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <streamio.h>


int main(){
    int V[p];
    char A[] = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};
    char *ch;

    ch = &V[p];
}
```

Comment: Брр... А в чем у вас разница между вектором и массивом? :)

Comment: Я просто изначально не знаю как создать вектор,вроде прочитав пару статьей я понял что вектор это и есть массив,но потом наткнулся на более сложные статьи где создаются отдельные библиотеки для векторов

Comment: Что такое "вектор" в вашем случае? О каких именно "векторах"  и где вы читали?

Comment: @Cyaneyed, не вдаваясь в подробности, в «бытовом» смысле слов — да, обычно это одно и тоже... но если речь идёт о каких-то конкретных типах данных с названиями «vector» или «array» из библиотек и/или в языках отличных от Си (в частности в C++), то под этими названиями могут пониматься разные вещи.

Comment: @Cyaneyed, если хотите задавать более осмысленные вопросы (и получать на них полезные ответы), то прочтите что-нибудь (например, [K&R](https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf)) по языку Си.

Comment: У вас два массива с разным типом данных. Нужно в цикле поэлементно присвоить с преобразованием типа.